# Another way - Connect to Hive through Spark not JDBC

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, apache-spark, hive

In the last week, I got a mission: Connect to my remote Hive Server. In the past 7 days, I have tried many ways to do this:

1. Connect to hiveserver in ***beeline***(Locally, in the server) ok!
2. Connect to hiveserver in ***spark-shell***(Locally, in the server) -- using HiveContext, ok!
3. Connect to hiveserver in ***jdbc client-side***(Remote, in the client) ok!

Yep, I wanna say all these work well(thank you all in `stackoverflow` who asked the same questions before:) ), but I do really want to change a way to connect Hive by using `hivecontext` in my client side...It fails, too many exception. So I come here and ask for help:

- Can we connect to hive by using ***hiveContext*** in the client-side (it means `hive-site.xml` is in the server not client)?
- Can anyone show me a simple example?

PS: Below are my commands:

> 1. $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-all.sh -- work!
> 2. $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --service metastore work!
> 3. $HIVE_HOME/bin/hiveserver start work! -- can connect to hive use beeline
> 4. $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-master.h
> 5. $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://master:7077
> 6. Begin to coding in my Eclipse(client-side), SparkConf -> SparkContext -> HiveContext(Exception!).

I will appreciate if you help me :)